# paragraphSpacingBefore in NSParagraphStyle causes caret to be above the text in UITextView

Tags: swift, uitextview

When I assign `paragraphSpacingBefore` property in `NSMutableParagraphStyle`, the caret of UITextView is above the text when typing. How do I fix this?

```
func something() -> NSMutableParagraphStyle {

    let paraStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paraStyle.paragraphSpacing = quoteParagraphSpacing
    paraStyle.lineSpacing = 10

    paraStyle.paragraphSpacingBefore = 20
    paraStyle.alignment = .left
    return paraStyle

}
```

This function is used like this.

```
textView.typingAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle.rawValue: something(), ....]
```

Screenshot

[image: As I type, the text appears at the bottom area while the caret is on top]

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question

Comment: can you also show the issue with the caret through a screenshot

Comment: just uploaded. Thank you for your patience and time.

Comment: Do you know how to solve this?